# How to check if a char is upper/lowercase?

Tags: java, parameters, lowercase

The following code is supposed to convert letters to numbers and give the sum, but ignore any letters that are uppercase.

Example:

The input `abcde` should return 15. The input `abCde` should return 12.

Any help is appreciated.

```
static int strScore(String str[], String s, int n) { 
    int score = 0, index=0; 

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { 
        if (str[i] == s) { 

        for (int j = 0; j < s.length(); j++) 
            score += s.charAt(j) - 'a' + 1; 
            index = i + 1; 
            break; 
        } 
    } 

    score = score * index; 
    return score; 
} 

public static void main(String[] args) {        
    String str[] = { "abcde" };
    String s = "abcde"; 

    int n = str.length; 
    int score = strScore(str, s, n); 
    System.out.println( score); 
}
```

Comment: Why do you need `String str[] = { "abcde" };` which has one which equals `s` ? Why do you need `n` when you can simply use `str.length` ? Also what is recursive in this solution ?

Answer (score 4):

Use `Character.isLowerCase(...)`.

So this is what your `strScore` method should look like:

```
static int strScore(String str[], String s, int n) { 
    int score = 0, index = 0; 
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { 
        if (str[i].equals(s)) { 
            for (int j = 0; j < s.length(); j++) {
                char c = s.charAt(j);
                if(Character.isLowerCase(c)) // <-- This is the important part
                    score += c - 'a' + 1;
            }
            index = i + 1; 
            break; 
        } 
    }

    score = score * index; 
    return score; 
}
```

As pointed out in the comments, there is no need for the `str` and therfore neither the `n` parameter. This is a better version:

```
static int strScore(String s) { 
    int score = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        if(Character.isLowerCase(c))
            score += c - 'a' + 1;
    }

    return score; 
}
```

Comment: Try `static int strScore(String s, int n) {` and simply removing the redundant `if (str[i].equals(s)) { `. You'll get the same results. +1 anyway because the method signature is in the question.

Comment: @c0der I'm aware that it's unnecessary, but this is how OP showed it in the question and I only wanted to change what's necessary. I'll add a clean version though.

Answer (score 2):

There are two things to address:

1. You have used `==` to compare strings. You need to use `.equals`
2. You need to put a check like `if(s.charAt(j)>= 'a' && s.charAt(j)<'z')`

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { 
    if (str[i].equals(s)) { 
        for (int j = 0; j < s.length(); j++) 
            if(s.charAt(j)>= 'a' && s.charAt(j)<'z') {
                score += s.charAt(j) - 'a' + 1;
```

Comment: I used `if(s.charAt(j)>= 'a' && s.charAt(j)<'z')` in the solution I proposed. Thanks. +1. I think `if (str[i].equals(s))` is not needed.

Comment: Thanks, @c0der for the support.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid passing `String str[] = { "abcde" };` which has one element which equals `s`
to The method. You can also avoid passing `n` which is an simply `str.length()`:

```
static int strScore(String s) {
    int score = 0, index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        for (char c : s.toCharArray()) { 
            if(c >= 'a' && c <'z') {     //alternatively if(Character.isLowerCase(c))
                score += c - 'a' + 1;
            }
        }
        index = i + 1;
        break;
    }
    score = score * index;
    return score;
}
```